# MPI - Equivalent of MPI_SENDRCV with asynchronous functions

Tags: mpi, openmpi, inter-process-communicat

I know that `MPI_SENDRECV` allow to overcome the problem of deadlocks (when we use the classic `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV` functions).

I would like to know if `MPI_SENDRECV(sent_to_process_1, receive_from_process_0)` is equivalent to:

```
MPI_ISEND(sent_to_process_1, request1)
MPI_IRECV(receive_from_process_0, request2)
MPI_WAIT(request1)
MPI_WAIT(request2)
```

with asynchronous `MPI_ISEND` and `MPI_RECV` functions?

From I have seen, `MPI_ISEND` and `MPI_RECV` creates a fork (i.e. 2 processes). So if I follow this logic, the first call of `MPI_ISEND` generates 2 processes. One does the communication and the other calls `MPI_RECV` which forks itself 2 processes.

But once the communication of first `MPI_ISEND` is finished, does the second process call `MPI_IRECV` again? With this logic, the above equivalent doesn't seem to be valid...

Maybe I should change to this:

```
MPI_ISEND(sent_to_process_1, request1)
MPI_WAIT(request1)
MPI_IRECV(receive_from_process_0, request2)
MPI_WAIT(request2)
```

But I think that it could be create also deadlocks.

Anyone could give to me another solution using `MPI_ISEND`, `MPI_IRECV` and `MPI_WAIT` to get the same behaviour of `MPI_SEND_RECV`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I usually do this on node i communicating with node i+1:

```
mpi_isend(send_to_process_iPlus1, requests(1))
mpi_irecv(recv_from_process_iPlus1, requests(2))
...
mpi_waitall(2, requests)
```

You can see how ordering your commands this way with non-blocking communication allows you (during the ... above) to perform any computation that does not rely on the send/recv buffers to be done during your communication. Overlapping computation with communication is often crucial for maximizing performance.

`mpi_send_recv` on the other hand (while avoiding any deadlock issues) is still a blocking operation. Thus, your program must remain in that routine during the entire send/recv process.

Final points: you can initialize more than 2 requests and wait on all of them the same way using the above structure as dealing with 2 requests. For instance, it's quite easy to start communication with node i-1 as well and wait on all 4 of the requests. Using `mpi_send_recv` you must always have a paired send and receive; what if you only want to send?

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought there were 2 processes after first MPI_ISEND, one which deals with the communication (send to process 1 in my above example) and the other which passes to MPI_IRECV function. In this way, I thought that MPI_IRECV should be called twice times (after the fork and when the first call was finished). In my example,  MPI_WAIT is just blocking until request_1 is acheived : we cannot say that each MPI_ISEND and MPI_IRECV do a fork (creates 2 processes like a POSIX pthread point of view ), is right ? What's the underlying implementation of MPI_WAIT (is it POSIX "pthread_join" ?) ?

Comment: It's bad to call them processes because you're already splitting up your problem using MPI processes (or ranks). However, if you really want to think of it this way, then yes there is a fork where 1 "process" deals with communication and 1 "process" continues on in the code. Note that the communication "process" dies as soon as the communication finishes though. So your `waitall` is only intended for each MPI process -- not for each "process" created from the fork.

Comment: As to the underlying implementation of `mpi_wait`, it is dependent on the MPI implementation that you are using. The MPI standard does not dictate how functions are implemented, but rather only the results of an MPI-compliant implementation. Lastly, pthreads and MPI are two different schools of thought, so I wouldn't compare them. It's like trying to compare OpenMP and MPI... they're just fundamentally different ways to create parallel code.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `recv_from_process_i` ?

Comment: @mort No: You're on process i. Why would process i be receiving a process from itself?

Answer (score 1):

There's some dangerous lines of thought in the question and other answers. When you start a non-blocking MPI operation, the MPI library doesn't create a new process/thread/etc. You're thinking of something more like a parallel region of OpenMP I believe, where new threads/tasks are created to do some work.

In MPI, starting a non-blocking operation is like telling the MPI library that you have some things that you'd like to get done whenever MPI gets a chance to do them. There are lots of equally valid options for when they are actually completed:

1. It could be that they all get done later when you call a blocking completion function (like `MPI_WAIT` or `MPI_WAITALL`). These functions guarantee that when the blocking completion call is done, all of the requests that you passed in as arguments are finished (in your case, the `MPI_ISEND` and the `MPI_IRECV`). Regardless of when the operations actually take place (see next few bullets), you as an application can't consider them done until they are actually marked as completed by a function like `MPI_WAIT` or `MPI_TEST`.
2. The operations could get done "in the background" during another MPI operation. For instance, if you do something like the code below:

   ```
   MPI_Isend(..., MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
   MPI_Irecv(..., MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Waitall(2, req);
   ```

   The `MPI_ISEND` and the `MPI_IRECV` would probably actually do the data transfers in the background during the `MPI_BARRIER`. This is because as an application, you are transferring "control" of your application to the MPI library during the `MPI_BARRIER` call. This lets the library make progress on any ongoing MPI operation that it wants. Most likely, when the `MPI_BARRIER` is complete, so are most other things that finished first.
3. Some MPI libraries allow you to specify that you want a "progress thread". This tells the MPI library to start up another thread (not that thread != process) in the background that will actually do the MPI operations for you while your application continues in the main thread.

Remember that all of these in the end require that you actually call `MPI_WAIT` or `MPI_TEST` or some other function like it to ensure that your operation is actually complete, but none of these spawn new threads or processes to do the work for you when you call your nonblocking functions. Those really just act like you stick them on a list of things to do (which in reality, is how most MPI libraries implement them).

The best way to think of how `MPI_SENDRECV` is implemented is to do two non-blocking calls with one completion function:

```
MPI_Isend(..., MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
MPI_Irecv(..., MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
MPI_Waitall(2, req);
```